# 'grep --color' only shows limited number of matches and duplicates input lines

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash, color

I have a lengthy string on one line and want to highlight all occurrences of a character/substring using `grep --color` on the command-line.
However, this only highlights matches in 'chunks' of 32. If there are more than 32 matches on one line, then only the first 32 are highlighted, the input string is repeated and the next chunk of 32 matches is highlighted on the next line(s). For example (replacing 'red' with 'bold'):

`for i in {1..4}; do echo -n 1234567890; done | grep --color "[0123456789]"`

**12345678901234567890123456789012**34567890

12345678901234567890123456789012**34567890**

How can I get all the matches on one line without duplicated input lines?

I am using Darwin on Big Sur and have tried bash and zsh. Duplication is not an issue if I don't use the `--color` flag or do use `-o`. Everything works as expected in Linux (Fedora 7.3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with BSD grep which is part of macOS. It works if you install GNU grep via Homebrew (use `ggrep` then).